# How to integrate Tosca CI on AWS code build pipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, tosca

Do someone know is it possible to execute tosca scripts in AWS code pipeline?

Comment: what scripts do you mean? Tosca has no scripts.

Comment: test cases I mean..for example if test cases are stored in aws code commit..aws code pipeline should communicate with tosca and execute the tc's